# Differences in array declaration in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsmutablearray, declaration

What's the difference between `var list = NSMutableArray()` and `var list:NSMutableArray = []` when declaring in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no effective difference.

With the first statement you are using the type inference feature of Swift. You create an instance of a class and from the assignment of that instance to a var the compiler infers the type.

In the second statement you explicitly define the type of `list`. <s>The assignment on the right side of the equal sign now instantiates an empty Swift Array but due to the explicit type of NSMutableArray it will be casted to this class.</s> 
The right expression of the equal sign does the same as `NSMutableArray()`does, but by using `[]` you have a smart shorthand option to instantiate the NSMutableArray with values like this `[2,1,4]` or `[someObject, someOtherObject]`etc.
Thanks to @Neo.

In the second statement the compiler would not complain about leaving the instantiation on the right side, it just would be nil implicitly. On the other hand the first statement without the `NSMutableArray()` expression would not be possible.

Keep in mind that `NSMutableArray`is a class from the Foundation framework and was primarily used in Objective-C context, whereas Swift offers an own collection type for this kind of lists. They are not the same, but implicitly casted by the compiler.

Hope this makes things clear.

Comment: Correct. And, as this answer explains in the end, we should really use the "Swift version" of array because it is better integrated with the language, it is based on a Struct and does offer generics. NSMutableArray belongs to the past.

Answer (score 1):

Just like JulianM said, there is no difference... Both are declaring / instantiating an NSMutableArray :-)

The only "difference" that there is

```
var list = NSMutableArray()
```

This line of code declares list and inherits his type of the instantiated NSMutableArray...

```
var list:NSMutableArray = []
```

While this line of code declares list AS NSMutableArray and instantiates it as an NSMutableArray...

But thats just a writing difference... Both mean the same...